# Display HTML code based on the result of javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I  have a form with a textfield as follows:-

```
    <form name = "myform" id="div" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "action.php" onsubmit = "return ValidationTest()">

<textarea type="textarea" size="1200" name = "RequestDescription" id = "RequestDescription" style="width:475px; height :102px;" class="form-control" rows="5" ></textarea>
```

The form has 2 Submit buttons.

```
<input type="Submit" name ="sub" id ="sub" value="sub">
<input type="Submit" name ="submit" id ="submit" value ="Submit">
```

When the first submit button is clicked, the data from the textarea is saved into a temporary table in the database, so that the user can edit whenever he/she wants to.

When the second submit button is clicked, the data in the textarea is saved permanently into a table, and the user cannot edit it anymore.

I want to display the form with the textarea with the data from the temporary database, whenever, the user has clicked the first submit button successfully(Validation using function ValidationTest returns true ), until the second submit button is clicked successfully.

Comment: have you tried using ajax to get the data from your database without the need to refresh the page?

Comment: AJAX is the best way in the your case. And don't use 2 submit buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Before that in mysql add a column "editable" set value for this based on POST value as below.

in action.php check for below

```
if(isset($_POST['sub']) {
//here update your editable to 1 which means you can edit
}
else if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
//here update your editable to 0 which means you can't edit value
}
```

And one more thing you have to do is before clicking on edit value you have to check editable value.. if its 0 dont allow to edit and if its 1 then allow the user to edit.